# Detect when iphone rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to be able to detect and get notification, when the user is rotate to landscape or portrait mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a UIViewController, it gets appropriate messages automatically. (See my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_rotation) If you just want general notifications, see the UIDevice docs.